# What would you call someone who sells information?

Tags: meaning

Is there an actual term? Just wondering since in movies or books there are those whom have information that other characters want or need and thus pay 'em for such information.

Comment: Informer? News monger?

Comment: Snitch? Stool pigeon? Narc?

Comment: Information today is a commodity and one dealing commercially in it should naturally be treated the same as one dealing in any other commodity. It does not require a specific definition to identify a seller of information as distinct from the generic term(s).

Comment: You could look up _spy_ in a thesaurus for even more candidates – _mole_ is another good one. (Those words are more hypernyms, though, since some spies are motivated by ideological reasons, more so than financial ones.)

Comment: The Shadow Broker. Oh, wait - this isn't [scifi.se] or [gaming.se]?

Comment: It's simply unclear if you mean **a criminal that sells information to the cops** or if you mean someone like (say) an analyst at a stock brokerage.  You should clarify this.

Answer (score 14):

You're probably thinking of an [***information broker***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_broker):

> a person or company providing information to clients for a fee -- definition from [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/information+broker)

TVTropes.com also lists a [***knowledge broker***](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/KnowledgeBroker):

> This is the person who always seems to have the dirt on everybody. The person who runs an information-gathering system, with a network of informers.

Comment: @NoActualName Note that this term usually carries the connotation of professional, consultant, or (in fiction) hacker. It wouldn't suit a criminal-class character, except facetiously.

Comment: @BraddSzonye The way I read the question, that's exactly what OP is looking for. All the other terms suggested imply a unscrupulous or underhanded character.

Comment: It looks to me more like a class distinction: "information broker" for white collar informants, and "informant" for underworld information brokers. ;)

Comment: Works so long as the information is sourced from elsewhere. One doesn't *broker* for what one owns (belongs to oneself) -- there need to be three parties for a brokerage.

Comment: I feel these are obscure, rather bizarre, terms that are rarely used.

Answer (score 8):

In crime fiction: [**informant**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Informant) or **CI** (for *confidential/criminal informant*).

Answer (score 0):

In police and crime fiction lingo: a paid informant
as used in *Confidential Informant* by John Madinger (p.211);  [Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=aK1fo5LhgOYC&pg=PA211&dq=paid+informant&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwic2eCynd_LAhXG0h4KHYUQDLEQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=paid%20informant&f=false)

Comment: Paid or not, *informant* was already in the earlier answers.

Comment: OK, so, should I remove my answer and my research? informant may or may not be paid. An informant may be informing for other non-monetary reasons, like immunity from prosecution. Does that meet with your approval??

Comment: Don't remove. I just gave a heads up. Other users may react unfavourably

Comment: NVZ, let them eat cake, poor dears. I am feeling rather prickly today. :)

Comment: No, because the link goes directly to a google book, which I just checked and is fine. I am not responsible for how links to google books look when they take you to a specific page!

Comment: At least I tried. It's fine. :)

Comment: I made the link neater.  If you don't like it, just roll it back.  (It still goes directly to your page.)    Tip:  [what you want highlighted](address)